# Design pattern for assembling disperate data?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am designing a system which assembles disperate data in a standard row/column type output.

Each column can:

- Exist in an independent system.
- Can be paginated.
- Can be sorted.
- Each column can contain millions of rows.

And the system:

- Needs to be extensible so different tables of different columns can be outputted.
- The final domain object is known (the row).
- The key is constant across all systems.

My current implementation plan is to design two classes per column (or one class column that implements two interfaces).  The interfaces would:

1. Implement a pagination and sorting.
2. Implement "garnishing"

The idea is that the table constructor would receive information about the current sort column and page.  Which would then return a list of appropriate keys for the table.  This information would be used to create a list of the domain object rows which would then be passed in turn to each of the column "garnishing" implementations so that each columns information could be added in turn.

I guess my question is - what design patterns would be recommended - or alternative design decisions would people use for assembling disperate data with common keys and variable columns.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific as to what this disperate data is? Maybe give two examples, one from each "system", just to make yourself clearer.

Comment: The pattern should be independent of the system.  The idea is it doesn't matter which system it comes from just that you have a common key that works in all systems, which is ultimately used to link the data.

Comment: When you say "Each column can contain millions of rows", do you mean the data will be contained in these "column" objects?

Comment: To me, this sounds more like a question of design, not design pattern. Your goal is to create an application that will most likely be comprised of a number of patterns (MVC, Observer, Visitor, so on), not of a single pattern. If you're asking what the core design pattern could be, then i guess it would depend upon the source of your data maybe..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I completely understood what you're trying to do, but from what I gather, you want to store rows of arbitrary data in a way that will allow you to make structured tables from it later on. What I would do in this case (assuming you're using Java) is make a very simple `Column` interface that would just have a "value" property:

```
public interface Column {
    String value;
}
```

Then, you could make columns by implementing `Column`:

```
public class Key implements Column {
    String value = new String();

    public Key(String keyValue){
        this.value = keyValue;
    }
}
```

So then you can make a class called `DataRow` (or whatever you like) whose objects would contain the actual data. For example, you could have a method in that class that would allow you to add data:

```
public class DataRow {

    List<Column> data = new ArrayList<Column>();

    public DataRow(String key){
        this.setColumn(new Key(key));
    }

    public void setColumn(Column columnData) {
        this.data.add(columnData);
    }

    public Column getColumn(Class column){
        for(Column c : this.data){
            if(c.getClass().equals(column)){
                return c;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

As you can see, you can call the method `setColumn()` by giving it a new `Column` object. This will allow you to add any data you like of any type to the `DataRow` Object. Then, to make some tables, you could have a function that takes a `List` of `DataRows`, and a `List` of classes, that would then return only the objects which have data from the row specified:

```
public List<DataRow> createTable(List<DataRow> data, List<Class<? extends Column>> columns){
    List<DataRow> table = new ArrayList<DataRow>();
    for(DataRow row : data){
        DataRow ret = new DataRow(row.getColumn(Key.class).value);
        for(Class column : columns){
            if(row.getColumn(column.getClass()) != null )ret.setColumn(row.getColumn(column.getClass()));
        }
        table.add(ret);
    }
    return table;
}
```

This will allow you to "create" tables using your data, and the columns you want to include in the table.

Note that I wrote this code to convey an idea, and that it's pretty messy at the moment. But I hope this will help you in some small way.

Comment: This is good in that it is very flexible.  But it doesn't address the construction of that data.  I imagine the pattern chooses a column to paginate and sort on which returns a set of keys, which is then passed to the other columns in order to garnish them with data.

I imagine the final syntax to be of the kind:

new AccountTableBuilder().paginate(ScoreColumn).garnish(AddressColumn).garnish(JobTitleColumn).garnish(OpenIdColumn);

Comment: That way could be done as well. Since you asked for alternative designs, I offered this one. The reason I wrote it this way is because I believe it to be somewhat simpler. As for the construction of data, if a production-quality version of the code above is in place, you could create data simply by making a new `DataRow` object and calling `setColumn()` on it as many times as you like. Is that what you meant?